# Error while Restoring .mdb and .log file of Sql Server 2005 on Server

Tags: sql-server

when I restored my sql server 2005  database on server 
I got error 
SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: torn page (expected signature: 0x0; actual signature: 0x400300). It occurred during a read of page (2:0) in database ID 12 at offset 0000000000000000 in file 'E:\MSSQL_DB\admin_log.ldf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

It working on my local machine
what is exactly problem???

Answer (score 0):

The database page has become corrupt.  Normally this wouldn't be that big a deal as you could probably repair the corrupt page by using DBCC CHECKDB.  However this is a system object page (a page which contains system objects) so the database will need to be restored from a full backup.

You can run DBCC CHECKDB for the database in question to see the exact object which is corrupt to ensure that it is a system object.

Odds are this is because of a problem with your disks.  Either a disk is failing or a RAID controller is failing.